# PowerShell Script only works from PowerShell Console and not from ISE

Tags: powershell

I am very very new to PowerShell. I am trying to delete a set of Test Results files in folders through PowerShell. When I run the code through PowerShell console, it works. The same code doesn't work through ISE.
Below is the code :

```
Set-Location -Path "Path";

$testResultsFolder = Get-ChildItem -Include *TestResults -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object FullName;
$date = Get-Date;
$limit = 30;


foreach($testResult in $testResultsFolder)
{
    $resultsPath = Get-Item $testResult.FullName;
    Get-ChildItem -Path $resultsPath -Recurse -Force |  Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $date.Subtract($_.LastWriteTime).Days -gt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force;
}
```

This works fine from PowerShell console but not from ISE. The ISE does not show any error. It says 'Completed'. Can somebody throw some light on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: 1. Close and reopen the ISE. 2. Put the code in a `.ps1` script file. 3. Run the script file in the ISE by typing its name and pressing `Enter` at the ISE's PowerShell prompt. You will note that it runs identically.

Comment: If you're not running it as a script, your variables are polluting your session in ISE.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I tried your suggestion, it goes on fine but no files get deleted. But when I run using the same code in Console, it deleted the files properly.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I am running it as a script. When I run the same ps1 file from console, it still doesn't delete files.

Comment: @PraveenTata Your title doesn't match what you're saying now.

Comment: The one this I can notice is when I use "Set-Location" it shows the location that I set and also the location of the .ps1 file like this:
PS C:\Praveen\Project\NEW\Test> C:\Users\TATA\Documents\Delete.ps1
when I am expecting only PS C:\Praveen\Project\NEW\Test>

Does this make any difference?

Comment: If the paths are different, then of course you will have different results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

*Delete.ps1*

```
#Requires -Version 3
$Path = 'C:\Temp'

$Cleanup = (Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Include '*TestResults' -Recurse -Directory).FullName

ForEach ($Folder in $Cleanup)
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -File -Recurse -Force |
        Where-Object { $PSItem.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) } |
        Remove-Item -Force
}
```

Using `Set-Location` can result in inconsistent results, especially if you're using dynamic variables.  I'd suggest using a variable target so you're getting consistent results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this by replacing the $Path with mine. It says "Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Directory'."

Comment: @PraveenTata That means you're on `PSv2`.  I put `#requires` in there for a reason

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late reply. I was trying some things. I will see if I can resolve this issue because this is on my office laptop and cannot update it by myself.

Comment: I got it working. I think this is the silliest mistake, but I am very new to PowerShell, like 3 days old :) I copied the directory to other location (Not C:\ drive) and ran my existing script and it worked. I think there was some permissions issue through ISE and not from console. @ TheIncorrigible1 thanks a lot for the help. @Bill_Stewart thank you too.